# Modern keyboard controller

Tags: microcontroller, keyboard

Can someone tell me what types of microcontrollers are used in modern keyboards. I would like to make my own keyboard and I think the best for me is something from AVR like atmega32u4, but I want to know what is used in large scale production.

Comment: They most likely have a specialized ASIC.

Comment: Probably specialised ones; a search turns up http://www.ene.com.tw/english/pro/ecdetail.php?pid=1

Comment: atmega32u4 would be a good one to start with.

Comment: Please be advised that a keyboard controller outputs a 20 bit scan code as 2 bytes with start and stop bits, whether it is PS-2 or USB output. Bios converts it to ascii, and keeps track of caps lock, etc. Bios notifies the calling program when data is ready in the queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, most modern consumer keyboards have specialized/integrated microcontrollers.   If you just want to make your own keyboard you should use a 10x11 keyboard matrix to have at most 110 keys (101 keys is the standard for US keyboards, 104 for windows keyboards).   So you would need at least 21 IO pins.

Here are 12,390 microcontrollers that you can choose from that all have USB capability and all have >= 21 pins:

https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/embedded-microcontrollers/685?k=usb+microcontrollers&k=&pkeyword=usb+microcontrollers&imin2208=21&FV=ffe002ad&mnonly=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25

A 32u4 has 20 IO pins and USB connectivity so you might just want to choose that if you are ok with having at most 100 keys.